# Getting 3 minimum numbers from np.min(array)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to use np.min to get more than 1 minimum number from matrix?

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,0]])
```

Expected result for 3 minimum numbers

```
>>[0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten and sort the array and get first 3 elements.

```
sorted(x.flatten())[:3]
Out[275]: [0, 1, 2]
```

Or a faster approach:

```
sorted(sum(x.tolist(),[]))[:3]

%timeit sorted(sum(x.tolist(),[]))[:3]
The slowest run took 7.38 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.14 µs per loop

%timeit sorted(x.flatten())[:3]
The slowest run took 11.54 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.97 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on flattend view -

```
x.ravel()[x.ravel().argsort()[:3]]
```

More performant one with [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) -

```
x.ravel()[x.ravel().argpartition(range(3))[:3]]
```

Or with `sort` to sort it afterwards -

```
np.sort(x.ravel()[x.ravel().argpartition(3)[:3]])
```

If you don't care about the numbers being sorted, skip `sort` -

```
x.ravel()[x.ravel().argpartition(3)[:3]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: x
Out[44]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 0]])

In [45]: x.ravel()[x.ravel().argsort()[:3]]
Out[45]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [48]: x.ravel()[x.ravel().argpartition(range(3))[:3]]
Out[48]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [52]: np.sort(x.ravel()[x.ravel().argpartition(3)[:3]])
Out[52]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [47]: x.ravel()[x.ravel().argpartition(3)[:3]]
Out[47]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: `argpartition` is the way to go.  Its *O(log n)* where `argsort` is *O(n log n)*